# Buscar archivos en una carpeta con PHP

Tags: php, html, imagen

Tengo una carpeta con N número de archivos con distintas extensiones, cuando subo el archivo a la carpeta lo renombro con un numero, por ej: 1.jpg o 4.docx o 7.pdf. Necesito que se liste el archivo sin saber que extensión tiene, es decir, que al yo cargar la página por metodo GET le envio el codigo del numero que tiene sin saber que extensión tiene. 
Ej: localhost/ejemplo/index.php?codigo=1
Lo que necesito es que la página vaya y me busque a la carpeta archivos, el archivo que se llame 1 independiente de la extensión que tenga. Gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué haz intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: He buscado en internet como hacerlo pero no encuentro respuesta, lo unico que aparece es como listar todo lo que esta en el directorio, o buscar un archivo con una extensión especifica

Comment: de que manera quieres presentar el archivo? por descarga o por web? otro(?)

Comment: Pero que haz intentado tu hasta el momento, muestra un poco de código para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: Simplemente deseo que se muestre el nombre del archivo en un link bien sea para ver o para descargar @KevinDelva

Answer (score 3):

Puedes realizar lo siguiente

```
// Ruta del directorio donde están los archivos
$path  = '/tmp'; 

// Arreglo con todos los nombres de los archivos
$files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));
```

Luego recorres el arreglo y le haces un simple `explode` a cada elemento

```
// Obtienes tu variable mediante GET
$code = $_GET['codigo'];

foreach($files as $file){
    // Divides en dos el nombre de tu archivo utilizando el . 
    $data          = explode(".", $file);
    // Nombre del archivo
    $fileName      = $data[0];
    // Extensión del archivo 
    $fileExtension = $data[1];

    if($code == $fileName){
        echo $fileName;
        // Realizamos un break para que el ciclo se interrumpa
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Esto sirve para cuando yo tenga un servidor remoto y deba buscar los archivos ".mp3" mediante la ruta absoluta del mismo?
(http:\\Mihost.com\Audios)